# Need to prevent user from running macro if #N/A is present in any worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro for one of our upload templates that uses a VLOOKUP formula to match descriptions to codes.  If it there is a new description, the user must create a new code.  After they create the new code, and the VLOOKUP returns a match, there is an additional macro that will copy/paste special/remove duplicates to prepare the file for upload.  I would like to incorporate something in the latter macro that will check if there are any outstanding VLOOKUP errors before proceeding to copy/paste special/remove duplicates.  There is a total of 9 worksheets and the row number will vary.

I found this function to check for the #N/A, but am not sure of the best way to use it in the existing macro:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(rngToCheck.Value)
```

Here is the copy/paste special/remove duplicates macro that I am currently using:

```
Sub PasteSpecialAndRemoveDups()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("1_Vendor_Upload").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:D").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("2_Lines").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:C").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("3_Parts_Info_Brand").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:B").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("4_Vendor_Brand").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:B").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("5_Product_Line_Catalog_Type").Select
    Cells.Select
   Range("A:B").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("6_Product_Lines_Catalog").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:F").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("7_Vendor_Catalogs").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:B").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("8_Vendor_Users").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:B").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("9_Parts").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A:P").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("1_Vendor_Upload").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells.Select
    Sheets("1_Vendor_Upload").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("2_Lines").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("3_Parts_Info_Brand").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("4_Vendor_Brand").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("5_Product_Line_Catalog_Type").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("6_Product_Lines_Catalog").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("7_Vendor_Catalogs").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("8_Vendor_Users").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    Sheets("9_Parts").Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, _
        7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), Header:=xlYes
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends, do you want your macro to skip to the next sheet and continue, or do you want to end the process and warn the user?

Comment: Yes, I would like the process to end and warn the user that there are #N/A values in the file.

Comment: Do you need to scan all sheets first and abort if any contain #N/A, or for example if it fails on the 3rd sheet, would you have let the first 2 through without issue?

Comment: @MattDonnan Good point... My answer assumes checking all first. Otherwise, you would need to segment out the If checks for each sheet.

Comment: I would need it to scan all sheets and not begin the copy/paste special/remove duplicates process on any sheets if there is any #N/A value present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go through each sheet and check for #N/A, then continue if possible.

```
Sub PasteSpecialAndRemoveDups() 
Dim sSheetsWithErrors As String
sSheetsWithErrors = vbNullString

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Sheets("1_Vendor_Upload").Cells.Value) Then
    sSheetsWithErrors = sSheetsWithErrors & ", "
End If
'Continue for each sheet

If Len(sSheetsWithErrors) > 0 Then
    sSheetsWithErrors = Left(sSheetsWithErrors, Len(sSheetsWithErrors) - 2) 'Remove trailing comma...
    MsgBox "There were errors found on the following sheets:" & vbCr & sSheetsWithErrors 'customize as desired
Else
'The rest of your Sub goes here
End If

End Sub
```

Also, using `Thing.Select`, then `Selection.DoStuff` is slower and more cumbersome. The same can usually be accomplished by jumping straight to `Thing.DoStuff`. If you need to do more than one 'DoStuff' step, try :

```
With Thing
    .DoStuff1
    .DoStuff2
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, Gaffi.  I added this to my code, and tried it with just the first sheet as a test, but received the following error:

Comment: Run-time error '7':
Out of memory at this line:  If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Sheets("1_Vendor_Upload").Cells.Value) Then

Comment: Oops...I figured it out.  I forgot to put the cell location in.  This is working perfectly.  Thank you!!

Comment: I made that same mistake with "Out of memory" I did find an alternative without IsNa although I fear it took me too long : ) Have a look anyways.

Comment: Glad I could help! @MattDonnan's solution should work as well, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it without IsNA:

```
Function FindNA() As Boolean

    Dim sht As Worksheet

        For Each sht In Application.Worksheets

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sht.Range("A:Z"), "#N/A") > 0 Then
            FindNA = True
            Exit Function
        End If

        Next

        FindNA = False

End Function
```

You could then simply call this check before proceeding with your code, if it's true then quit, if it's false then continue.

E.g.

```
If FindNA then
    'Don't continue
Else
    'Continue
End If
```

Comment: I am still fairly new to vba.  I inserted the function in a module and see that the function is available, but I'm not sure how to use it.